# Setting header color on scroll for each post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, event-handling

On this site [this site](http://www.amypreston.co.uk/), I have some code which you can see below which figures out the offset for each post from the top of the document and assigns a colour from each post to the header when it scrolls into view. I am having to wait for the window load event until the code works which really is not very elegant. Can anyone see how I can improve this code?

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var $header = $("header");
    var numberOfSections = $("section").length;   
    var sectionOffsets = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++) {
        sectionOffsets.push($("section").eq(i).offset().top);
    }            

    $(window).scroll(function () {
         $("section").each(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(this).offset().top - 180) {
                $("header").css('color', $(this).data("colour"));
            }
        });
    }).scroll();
});
```

Comment: What's the point of `$header`, `numberOfSections`, and `sectionOffsets`?

Comment: What's wrong with `load` event for you?

Comment: The load event is not very good as there are a lot of images on the page and the function does not work until all of the images are loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/vipawa/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

Instead of storing `section` positions on `window onload` time, which can be always kind of **inaccurate since your images might still load**...

get dynamically  the current position / size data of an element using:

[element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

using that JS method **you don't even need to calculate the `$(window).scrollTop()`**
 cause the returned value is the element's position respective to the `client` top (viewport top edge).

To retrieve only the one element that matches a *top criteria* you can use the [jQuery's `.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method and return the element which...

```
$section.filter(function(){
    var r = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    return  r.top + r.height - 100  > 0; // ...matches this
})
```

(`100` is the header height in this demo; set as desired or calculate dynamically)

Now, since jQuery filtered more than one element that matches that criteria of `(gbcr.top + gbcr.height - headeroffser) > 0` by going directly to chain another method to it like `.data()`, the value will be respective to the **first** of elements returned in the `.filter()` collection:

```
$header.css({
  color : $section.filter(function(){
    var r = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    return  r.top + r.height - 100 > 0;
  }).data().colour // is the colour data of the first of filtered elements
});
```

Store that colouring stuff inside a `setScrollColors` **function** and use like:

```js
$(function() { // DOM ready shorthand

  var $header  = $("header");  // Cache selectors
  var $section = $("section");

  function setScrollColors() {
    $header.css({
      color : $section.filter(function(){
        var r = this.getBoundingClientRect();
        return  r.top + r.height - 100 > 0;
      }).data().colour
    });
  }

  setScrollColors();                            // Call inside dom ready
  $(window).on("load scroll", setScrollColors); // call also on load and scroll

});
```

```css
*{margin:0;}
header{
  position:fixed;
  z-index:1;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  background:#f9f9f9;
  height:100px;
  border-bottom:1px solid currentColor;
}
#content{
  margin-top:100px;
}
section{
  min-height: 1000px;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  border-top:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header><h1>HEADER</h1></header>

<div id="content">
  <section data-colour="black">black</section>
  <section data-colour="red">red</section>
  <section data-colour="blue">blue</section>
  <section data-colour="green">green</section>
  <section data-colour="fuchsia">fuchsia</section>
  <section data-colour="orange">orange</section>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be a more elegant solution than my approach. I have never used "getBoundingClientRect" before. It seems very useful.